# "To steal the show" origin?

Tags: phrase-origin

Where does the phrase "to steal the show" come from? Lately I've heard it used for a movie.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When someone or something *steals the show*, they are the unexpected focus of (positive) attention.  If you go to a movie starring George Clooney, but realize afterward that all the scenes with a relatively unknown actress are the ones that you enjoyed most, you could say that the actress has stolen the show; you went with the expectation of enjoying George Clooney but found yourself largely ignoring him in favor of focusing on someone else entirely.

Answer (score 3):

It means **to focus** (or steal) **all the attention at an event** (you're stealing all the attention of the show).

The *New Oxford American Dictionary* says: “to attract the most attention and praise”.